# I am getting this error, this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key collectionView.' ,

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a UIViewController, and embedded I have a UICollectionView, I also have a sub class called ChatCell

```
ChatCell Subclass:
class ChatCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var chatLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var chatImage: UIImageView!

}

class ChatRoom: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {



    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView2: UICollectionView!
```

// My error was ^ I changed the name and I did not update the outlet in the storyboard! Make sure you have the correct outlets, or they will not be recognized by xcode.

```
    var secondClass : ChatCell?

    struct Object {
        var image: UIImage!
        var title: String!
    }

    // Properties
    var object: Object?
    var objects: [Object] = []
    var picker: UIImagePickerController!


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker?.allowsEditing = false
        picker?.delegate = self
        picker?.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        // NavigationBar Characteristics
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.black
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
        // self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Logout", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleLogout))
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.tintColor = UIColor.green
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "+", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(didSelectCreateButton))
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.tintColor = UIColor.green

    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as UICollectionViewCell
        let object = objects[indexPath.row]

        secondClass?.chatLabel.text = object.title ?? ""
        secondClass?.chatImage.image = object.image ?? UIImage()


        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return objects.count

    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

        switch info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        case let .some(image):
            object?.image = image
        default:
            break
        }

        picker.dismiss(animated: true) {
            self.showCellTitleAlert()
        }
    }

    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {

        object = nil

        dismiss(animated: true) {
            self.collectionView2!.reloadData()
        }
    }

    // Alerts

    func showCellTitleAlert() {

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Cell Title", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)

        alert.addTextField { $0.placeholder = "Title" }
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { _ in
            self.object = nil
        })
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Save", style: .default) { _ in
            self.object?.title = (alert.textFields?.first.flatMap { $0.text })!
            self.object.flatMap { self.objects.append($0) }
            self.collectionView2?.reloadData()
        })

        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    // Create new Cell
    ////////?//////////////
    @IBAction func didSelectCreateButton() {

        object = Object()

        present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

Comment: Make sure that all `@IBOutlet` wired to storyboard/xib correctly. Then clear derived data and clean the project. That should solve your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your storyboard (or xib) you have specified a connection to an outlet called `collectionView` but in your code you call it `collectionView2`.

Delete the bad connection and re-do it to point to your current variable name.

Comment: thanks for the help, Im just wondering why is that a bad connection?

Comment: It worked! Thank you I understand now what I did wrong.